# Get Average from last 26 entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Google's `jsapi` to draw a area chart, so I have to get two different averages.

The first one is for a specific person and the second one is for the entire company except for that person.

I am using this query to get the last 26 weeks from the specified person.

```
 SELECT TOP 26 DATE_GIVEN
 FROM CHECKS
 WHERE PERSON_NO='001'
 ORDER BY DATE_GIVEN DESC
```

But I need to modify that to get the last 26 weeks even if the person skips a week, and for missing weeks fill in a 0 and include it in the average.

But the second one is super hard and I don't know how to do it. Here is what I want to do:

1. Select all of the checks in the table expect for person_no=001
2. Group all of them per week
3. Select only the last 26 check weeks
4. If a week is missing for a person, fill in the value 0 and include it in the average.

I tried something like this but it's wrong:

```
 SELECT TOP 26 AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS W2
 FROM CHECKS
 WHERE NOT PERSON_NO='001'
 GROUP BY Datepart(week,DATE_GIVEN)
 ORDER BY DATE_GIVEN DESC
```

To make it a little more more clear:

I'm trying to get the weekly average for one person vs. the average of the rest of the company not including that person. The table name is `CHECKS` with columns `CHECK_NO, DATE_GIVEN, AMOUNT, PERSON_NO`.

I also tried something like this but I don't know if this is correct:

```
SELECT TOP 26 AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS W1
FROM CHECKS
WHERE PERSON_NO='001'
GROUP BY Datepart(week, DATE_GIVEN)

SELECT TOP 26 AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS W2
FROM CHECKS
WHERE NOT PERSON_NO='001'
GROUP BY Datepart(week, DATE_GIVEN)
```

[image]

Comment: So, you want the last 26 weeks?, because "the last 26 check averages" doesn't make much sense

Comment: Can you give example data and desired results? (I guess 3 weeks rather than 26 should be sufficient)

Comment: @Lamak sorry I didn't make it clear. I'm trying to get the weekly average for one person vs the average of the entire company but not to include them. the tables name is CHECKS AND IT HAS COULMN NAMED: CHECK_NO, DATE_GIVEN, AMOUNT, PERSON_NO

Comment: Is there **always** and **only** one check per person per week? Could any one person skip a week?

Comment: @ErikE ooh GOOD one, Yes they can skip a week and I want that to show also if possible, so if they skip a week the amount would be 0 and not skipped.

Comment: You should not use `TOP`here, as you want select data for last 26 calendar weeks, not last 26 records whatever the record date is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st one.
As you need to get data for *last 26 weeks* you need to subtract 26 weeks from current date. Since you want to include 0 for missing weeks, it is the same as diving the SUM of whatever you've got by 26.

```
Declare @weeks int = 26;

SELECT sum(CHECK_AMOUNT)/@weeks FROM CHECKS 
WHERE PERSON_NO='001'  and DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
```

For the rest of the company: (i) Get average checks for every one except your person for last 26 weeks; (ii) get average of those averages (no need to place 0 for a missing person here)

```
select avg (Person_Check_Amount) from
    (
    SELECT PERSON_NO, SUM(CHECK_AMOUNT)/@weeks 
         as Person_Check_Amount
    FROM CHECKS 
    WHERE PERSON_NO <> '001'  and DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
    GROUP BY PERSON_NO
    ) t
```

**UPDATE**

I have added `/COUNT (distinct PERSON_NO)` because number of people in the company varies from one week to another.

Now we can combine these queries to have single table for comparison. It can be done in a single query.

With common table expressions, which make logic more visible. Here I change `DATEPART`to `DATEDIFF`, so when we go back into previous year we keep counting number of weeks from today (25,26,..58,59...), not week number in the year (like 52)

```
DECLARE @weeks int = 26

;WITH Person AS (
   SELECT
     datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 AS Week,
     AVG(CHECK_AMOUNT) AS Person_Check_Amount
   FROM CHECKS
   WHERE PERSON_NO=11  AND DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
   GROUP BY datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate()) +1
)

, Company AS (
    SELECT week,
  AVG (COMPANY_Check_Amount) AS COMPANY_Check_Amount
    FROM (
       SELECT
         datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 AS Week,
         SUM(CHECK_AMOUNT)/COUNT(DISTINCT PERSON_NO) AS COMPANY_Check_Amount
       FROM CHECKS
       WHERE PERSON_NO<>11  AND DATE_GIVEN >= dateadd(ww, -@weeks, getdate())
       GROUP BY datediff(ww, DATE_GIVEN, getdate())+1 
    ) t
  GROUP BY Week
)

SELECT c.week
 , isnull(Person_Check_Amount,0)  Person_Check_Amount
 , isnull(Company_Check_Amount,0) Company_Check_Amount
FROM Person p
FULL OUTER JOIN Company c ON c.week = p.week
ORDER BY Week DESC
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f889/4)**

Comment: I forgot subquery alias - t. Check it out. Sorry for typo, I do not have console at hand.

Comment: this works great but it only shows me the 1 result I need it to show me all of the results for each week for the person vs the company for every 26 weeks ago all the way up to this week. starting from the oldest week (week 26) to the recent week (1).

Comment: Questions: each person has only 1 entry or may have multiple entries? Persons from the company - do you need to fill 0 if a person from a company does not work? (Ie. does total number of persons change every week or not)

Comment: Each person may have multiple entries. Yes, I would like to fill 0 if the person from a company doesn't work so it doesn't upset the AVG right ?? but I don't want to insert that info. into the database only place the zero to make the AVG more accurate... Yes, the total number of persons DOES change since not all of them work and get a check each week.

Comment: I such a noob!! Thank you so much for you help but I am totally lost now, I tired the examples above that you provided me and I'm getting a lot of errors, I tried to fix them but making small changes but I don't have a clue what I'm doing anymore. Can you please look at the info. above one more time and just dumb it out for me alil'

Comment: @msvuze I've tested my answer, provide SQLFilddle and deleted come comments.

Comment: The example is great and works in SQLFilddle but I have a small problem with my result. Look at the picture I have attached at the end of my question and week 52 shows up at the top instead of week 26 ?

Comment: I thought that it was the date format because I have MM/DD/YYYY and I then tried to replace DATE_GIVEN with: convert(varchar, DATE_GIVEN, 111)) but still the same results and week 52 shows up at the top instead of week 26

Comment: I just noticed if I change DECLARE @weeks int = 25 then it works fine, but is the data correct for the avg ?

Comment: Function `DATEPART` returns week number within year. If date falls into last year, it will start counting form 52-53 backwards.

Comment: Got it, This has help me so much! Thank you so much for all the time you took with me to explain me all of this, you are a great person! Thanks again!!!  I just need to learn now how to put this into the .asp page I tried to put it into a strQuery="...." and then do objRS.Open StrQuery to execute it but for some reason it doesn't work I guess this is another question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do the `top` in a subquery and then do the average:

```
select avg(check_amount) as w1
from (SELECT TOP 26 c.*
      FROM CHECKS
      WHERE PERSON_NO='001'
      ORDER BY DATE_GIVEN DESC 
     ) c
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be reversed? Get all of the averages, sort DESC and then select top 26 from that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 26 *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT AVG(check_amount) AS W2, DATE_GIVEN
    FROM Checks
    WHERE PERSON_NO='001'
    GROUP BY DATE_GIVEN    
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
) Top_26
```

Comment: I get this error when I try it, Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: This is still not doing exactly what it should. Looking into the solution now.

Comment: If I change the last line to ORDER BY Top_26.DATE_GIVEN DESC then it looks right but it orders it the wrong way and if I add ASC instead of DESC then it loads the super old data

Comment: You can get around the subquery issue by specifying top 100 percent. I've updated my query.

Comment: Also how do you do that if it's not the person_no='001' ??

Comment: You can filter the inner query with any criteria you like.

Comment: If you are trying to exclude 001 then WHERE person_no <> '001' should work.

Comment: The data is displayed correctly only it's going from the newest to oldest,, and I want it from the oldest to newest... I tried to replace DESC with ASC but then it gives me the wrong result. Better said the results are correct only the results need to change from top to bottom (Reverse)

Comment: Did you try sorting Top_26.Date_Given DESC (or the other field)?

Comment: @Mike Cheel oh I see I just have to add ORDER BY 2 ASC after the ) Top_26 line to make it go backwards. but how do we fix the if a week is missing issue that Stoleg mentioned.

Comment: Probably something using Row_Number to ensure I had 26 weeks of rows. Similar to the section 'Returning a subset of rows' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx found here. I would just build it into my query.