# SQL Server default for Select Top 1000 Rows

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to get this to default to the following: order by Id descending, or ordering by row creation date descending?

Comment: Do you mean the default for SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes when you right click the table name in SSMS

Comment: See my answer in this post. I think it is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17306241/426422. If you are meaning default for all queries I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I dont believe this could be flexible the way you think, you can SELECT * from any table but you cannot order by creation date on any table

Answer (score 9):

No.  The only property that can be modified is the amount of rows under Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Value for Select Top < n > Rows command.  Please note you can also modify the Edit Top < n > Rows and Select Top < n > Audit records.

You could write a separate stored procedure, add it to your master database, and add a shortcut under Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> Query Shortcuts.  Then in Management Studio, you could highlight the name of the schema and table and run the shortcut.  The stored procedure called could then do this for you.  Below is a sample stored procedure that would accomplish this goal but orders by the first column instead of a specific column name.  You can replace the 1 with a specific column name, but this is likely more flexible for your purposes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Test_OrderByFirstColumnDesc
    @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY 1 DESC';

PRINT @SqlCommand;

EXEC dbo.sp_ExecuteSQL @SqlCommand;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tools-->options-->SQL Server object explorer -->Commands

**Change Value for Edit Top  Rows Command ** to a higher number

Comment: How did this get any mod points?  It doesn't answer the question.